# How adding redundant data can get rid of complex join in Denormalization?

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, denormalization

I was going through Denormalizaition definition and I am wondering how adding redundant data can get rid of complex join ?

Comment: If your data is (fully) denormalized then there is nothing to join :)

Comment: @Oilver Just a quick question. Are everything is in one table in Denormalized data ?

Comment: And what *is* the definition of "denormalization" you were given?

Comment: @philipxy Can we conclude by going through the following definition of Denormalization that "Are everything in one table in Denormalization ?" 

Denormalization is "The process of adding redundant data to get rid of complex join, in order to optimize database performance. This is done to speed up database access by moving from higher to lower form of normalization."

Comment: That is a vague and poor "definition". Denormalization is, after you have normalized to some components, using the joins of some components instead of the components. (So you don't have to do those joins when you need them. But queries are more complex when you don't need them. And managing integrity is more difficult.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following two relations:

```
Department (department_id PK, department_name, manager_employee_id)
Employee (employee_id PK, employee_name, department_id)
```

To get a list of employee names together with their managers' names, we would need a query like the following:

```
SELECT e.employee_name, m.employee_name AS manager_name
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Department AS d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
INNER JOIN Employee AS m ON d.manager_employee_id = m.employee_id
```

Now, if we denormalize the transitive functional dependency `employee_id -> department_id -> manager_employee_id -> employee_name` into the Employee table, our tables could look like this:

```
Department (department_id PK, department_name, manager_employee_id)
Employee (employee_id PK, employee_name, department_id, manager_employee_id, manager_name)
```

Practically, this might not be a good design since the redundancies could result in data consistency if it's not carefully kept in sync. However, we'll ignore that risk for the purpose of this example.

With the new tables, we can now get the list of employee and manager names like this:

```
SELECT employee_name, manager_name
FROM Employee
```

Redundancy can help some queries to be expressed more simply, but it can introduce a risk of data inconsistency which needs to be carefully considered and controlled. Redundancy also requires more storage space and can make queries slower, since fewer rows can fit into a page on disk. On the other hand, it can make some queries faster by eliminating joins or calculations, and it can even be used to enforce consistency. Each case needs to be considered on its own merits.